# insertSheet method of Kendo Spreadsheet

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I was looking at the documentation for the insertSheet method for Kendo Spreadsheet, at the below link:
http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/spreadsheet#methods-insertSheet

I didn't see any examples on how to actually use this method. I tried searching on Kendo forums but didn't have any luck. Has anyone used this method or seen any examples of usage that we can use as a reference?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I have provided a very simple dojo showing how to insert a sheet and then rename it. 
https://dojo.telerik.com/AXulOsAS

If you look at the demo's for the spreadsheet control it gives you some insight into the control but this is still a relatively new element to the kendo UI suite so the documentation is a little sparse.

https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/spreadsheet/index

have added the dojo code here just in case:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Untitled</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.1.115/styles/kendo.common.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.1.115/styles/kendo.rtl.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.1.115/styles/kendo.default.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.1.115/styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css">

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.1.115/js/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.1.115/js/jszip.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.1.115/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script></head>
<body>



  <div id="ss">
  </div>






  <script>

    $('document').ready(function(){

      $('#ss').kendoSpreadsheet(); 

      var ss = $('#ss').data('kendoSpreadsheet'); 
      ss.insertSheet(); 


      ss.renameSheet(ss.sheets()[1], 'test 1'); 
    }); 

  </script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi David, appreciate your response. I tried clicking the dojo link, but got a pop-up saying there is an error with the page. Did the link expire?

Comment: Nope, the link is working fine for me. I have added the code from the dojo just in case. so you can copy it and run it.

Comment: Thanks for posting the code David. I can insert the sheet now, but just a quick follow-up. Is it possible to pass instance of worksheet to insertSheet method? I have an existing worksheet that needs to be inserted into this workbook, and was trying to do that. I can insert a blank sheet using your code, but tried passing reference to worksheet into the insertSheet method and it didn't seem to work. Do you know if this is possible?

Comment: I haven't worked with the spreadsheet control that much. You could try using the fromFile() method. but this will wipe any data you have in the current workbook. Otherwise you will need to parse out the contents of the worksheet and then pass that through as a new work sheet instance. If you have a pro license it may be worth contacting Telerik support for more info or ask on their pro forums for assistance.